# php trouble retrieveing a mysql blob

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to retrieve a blob from a mysql database. However, my query always returns 1, and does not trigger an error. I've been trying the things I found here and there, but I can never get it to return a  resource. I manually checked that the blob to be retrieved, so that does not seem to be the problem. Could someone please help me?

```
$id = 2;
$sqlFetch = "SELECT * FROM mallampati_images WHERE img_id = $id";
$sth = $wpdb->query($sqlFetch) or die ('query failed');
$a = mysql_num_rows($sth);
```

causes the error:

`Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given in /home/clients/4ceaa5faab208e8af4350138684e6d6d/web/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/functions.php on line 539
NULL`

Comment: Why are you using `mysql_`?

Comment: if you are using wordpress for querying, you shouldn't mix wordpress query methods with native mysql query methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will always return 1.

```
$sth = $wpdb->query($sqlFetch) or die ('query failed');
```

what you actually want is

```
if (false === ($sth = $wpdb->query($sqlFetch)) {
    die ('query failed');
}

... rest of code
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did. It gets a single cell out of a single row, but there are other wordpress functions available, such as `$wpdb->get_row`instead of `$wpdb->get_var`. It is in fact really simple, but I did not understand the `$wpdb`API at all.

```
$sth = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT img_blob FROM mallampati_images WHERE img_id = 1 ", OBJECT ) );
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $sth ).'"/>';
```